# 503 Error After Microsoft Request Routing Is Installed - 32 bit 64 bit madness

Tags: routes, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

I have a requirement to install the Microsoft Request Routing component for IIS 7.5 running on a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 64Bit machine.

After installing Microsoft Request Routing via the Web Platform installer our ASP.NET 4.0 application gets a "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

The Windows event log error details says:

```
The Module DLL 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Application Request Routing\requestRouter.dll' could not be loaded due to a configuration problem. The current configuration only supports loading images built for a AMD64 processor architecture. The data field contains the error number. To learn more about this issue, including how to troubleshooting this kind of processor architecture mismatch error, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=29349.
```

I can make this error go away by changing the application pool to run in 32 bit mode by changing the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" setting to true.

However I would prefer not to have to do that to resolve the issue.

My questions are:

1. Why is the Microsoft Request Routing feature trying to load a 32 bit version, isn't there a 64 bit version for it?
2. How do I resolve this issue without having to change my application pool to a 32 bit mode?

Answer (score 0):

having done some research into this I can inform you that there are currently two version of Microsoft's Application Request Routing one for 32-bit architecture and the other for 64-bit.

Although it does not say, I would presume that the Web Platform Installer version is only for 32-bit, in order to get a 64-bit specific version you are going to have to download from one these two locations:

http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2011/04/20/how-to-install-application-request-routing-arr-2-5-without-web-platform-installer-webpi.aspx

or

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7173

the blog (first URL) gives details on how to install into IIS once you have downloaded.

hope this proves useful.

Comment: I uninstalled what I had, followed what the article said by downloading and installing the 64 bit installers and I still get the same error. :-(

Answer (score 0):

What processor architecture are you using?

The error seems to suggest that only 64bit AMD processors are currently supported, perhaps it might be worth looking into a solution more specific to your processor.

I'm guessing your using an Intel CPU?

I'm aware that there are certain scenarios where running IIS in 32 bit mode on a 64 bit system is required.

Answer (score 0):

it might be worth looking at these installation guidelines on the IIS site found at this address:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/installing-application-request-routing-%28arr%29/install-application-request-routing

if these don't solve the issue it might well be worth either posting on the IIS forum:

http://forums.iis.net/

or posting on technet forum:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-gb/categories/